# Probability of symmetric difference

Tags: probability, proof-writing

How do we prove the following inequality?
$$\mathbb{P}[A\triangle B ]\geq \max\left \{ \mathbb{P}[A-B],\mathbb{P}[B-A] \right \}$$
I already proved that
$$\mathbb{P}[A\triangle B ]=\mathbb{P}[A]+\mathbb{P}[B]-2\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]$$
$$\left | \mathbb{P}[A]-\mathbb{P}[B] \right |\leq \mathbb{P}[A\triangle B ]$$

Comment: Can you use other inequalities or equalities? Perhaps the definition $P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: Yes yes I can use and I was looking for that kind of probability difference  that you posted , I think it would be easy to solve it now .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$$
$$P(B-A)=P(B)-P(B\cap A)$$
Using these we can rewrite the first relation as
$$P(A\triangle B)=P(A-B)+P(B-A)$$
Since probabilities are non-negative:
$$P(A\triangle B)\ge\max(P(A-B),P(B-A))$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove that $$P(A\Delta B)=P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)$$

Therefore, $P(A\Delta B)$ is no less than $P(A\setminus B)$ and no less than $P(B\setminus A)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)
$$
whence
$$
(A\setminus B)\subseteq A\Delta B\quad \text{and}\quad 
(B\setminus A)\subseteq A\Delta B.
$$
In particular
$$
P(A\setminus B)\leq P(A\Delta B)
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
P(B\setminus A)\leq P(A\Delta B)
$$
so that
$$
\max\{
P(A\setminus B), P(B\setminus A)
\}
\leq P(A\Delta B)
$$